# How to update state without refreshing page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to update my dashboard if there are any changes from backend as notification in Facebook.

I have two pages:

- A page for the user sending a request message
- A page for the user profile where the user can see all the request messages

If there is a new request message, the user needs to refresh the user profile in order to see the new message. I want the new message to be displayed without refreshing the page. Here is my code:

In a message page

```
state = {

    team: {
      message: 'Hi! I would like to join in your team! Please accept my request',
      invitation_message: 'Hi! I would like to invite you to join in my team.',
      email: '',
    },

  }
  // Invite user to a team
  handleInvite = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const jwt = userObject.jwt;
    const config = {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `bearer ${jwt}` },
    };     
    api
      .post('/teammembers', {
        team: this.state.teaminfo,
        profile: responseData.data[0],
        status: "invited",
        message: this.state.team.invitation_message,
      }, config)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          success_message: true,
        })
        console.log('Success', response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('An error occurred:', err);
      });

  }
```

In a user profile page

```
export class UserProfile extends React.Component {
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

state = {

    invited_teams:[],
    endpoint: "myurl"

  }
 componentDidMount() {
 const { endpoint } = this.state;
    //Very simply connect to the socket
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on('request', (data) => {
      this.setState({ state: data.requests });
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('userData')) {
      const userObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      api
        .get(`/profiles/?user=${userObject.user.id}`)
        .then(responseData => {
          this.setState({
            invited_teams: responseData.data
          })
        }
    }      
}
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: TLDR, could "shouldComponentUpdate" be of use ?

Comment: Low level solution: You can schedule a job (or setInterval) to get request every a certain time (for example every 5 minutes) and update the state of your request list. And higher solution, I think you should research long-polling technique.

Answer (score 0):

Use socket.IO library. You can set a listener on new request and then update the state.

```
socket.on('request' , (data) => {
  this.setState({state: data.requests});
});
```

Comment: Do I need to set a socket.io into backend??? I added the socket.io to my front end code, I got a cors issue. Could you check my code? I am not sure whether my code is correct or not. Thanks

Comment: Yes , you need to implement a it on the backend too . Check out the socket.io site , it has a very good documentation and easy to implement for realt time web apps. Are you using dev server for React or Serving built html+s page as static page? @kevin

Comment: I am using ReactJS for front end. the page should be dynamically. Ok I will investigate with my teammate about this. Thanks for your help so much :)

Comment: If you dont need to save requests on the backend you should pass down method from parent where you can update the parent state and pass down the parent state both of the page . I not sure if you understand what i am talking about :D. Ask if something not clear. @Kevin